# Android, what file defines the minimum screen brightness?

Tags: android, settings, screen, brightness, adjustment

Does anyone know which file defines minimum screen brightness available for use?
The one available for user with the slider adjustment. And where it might be located?

I have LeanageOS on my SGS4 but I believe that the screen is too bright in the night with the slider set to minimum and I'd like to adjust it even further. My device is rooted.

Comment: You will only be able to accomplish this with a rooted device.

Comment: This is what I have, my device is rooted.

Comment: I'm not sure where on a rooted device this can be found, but there is a lot of apps on google play that does what you want to do without a rooted device.

Comment: Yes, except I would like to avoid additional apps. I just need to extend the minimum range of this setting.